# Nodejs how to decide which function gets excecuted first?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am learning to integrate **Sequalize** in **NodeJS**. I have written two queries. The first one creates a product entry in the database and the other one retrieves all the entries from the database table. I have placed the create a query before the retrieve query, however the retrieve query gives a result before the create query gets executed.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and how to prevent it? I have pasted the code and result below.

Here are the scripts:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize('practiseapp','root','Current-Root-Password',{
    dialect:'mysql',
    host:'localhost'
});
const product = require("./models/product");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extented:false}));

sequelize.sync().then(result =>{
        console.log("Success");
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log("Error in connection mysql");
});


const addProduct = (req,res,next)=>{
    product.create({
    title:"Dhruv",
    imageUrl: "asdasdwadasd",
    description : 'How u doin'
}).then(function(user){
    console.log("Product Created");
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("cant create");
});
}
addProduct();

const findProduct = (req,res,next)=>{
    product.findAll().then(users => {
    console.log("Reached find all");
    console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
});
}
findProduct();

app.listen(3000);
```

This is the output of the execution:

```sh
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option app.js:10:20
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `imageUrl`, `description`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `products`
AS `product`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(255), `imageUrl` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `products` (`id`,`title`,`imageUrl`,`description`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);
Reached find all
All users: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Dhruv",
        "imageUrl": "asdasdwadasd",
        "description": "How u doin",
        "createdAt": "2019-06-05T17:39:43.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-06-05T17:39:43.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Dhruv",
        "imageUrl": "asdasdwadasd",
        "description": "How u doin",
        "createdAt": "2019-06-05T17:44:24.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-06-05T17:44:24.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Dhruv",
        "imageUrl": "asdasdwadasd",
        "description": "How u doin",
        "createdAt": "2019-06-05T17:44:34.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-06-05T17:44:34.000Z"
    }
]
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `products`
Success
Product Created
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is another way to do.

```
   const addProduct = (req,res,next)=>{
        product.create({
        title:"Dhruv",
        imageUrl: "asdasdwadasd",
        description : 'How u doin'
    }).then(function(user){
        console.log("Product Created");
        return product.findAll().then(users => {
                console.log("Reached find all");
                console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
            });

    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("cant create");
    });
    }
    addProduct()
```

Comment: this is `Promise` based.I not use `Promise` keyword becoz sequelize is internally promise based

Comment: You are writing a function inside a function. This is not an efficient way to do it.

Comment: i'm doing according to your architecture  of code and this is efficient. It is `Promise` not just a function, man

Comment: I studied a bit more. Your solution works. Also, we can use a timeout but its the same thing. Another method which I liked is async and await. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: `async await` is another ways of doing promise.

Answer (score 0):

As Node.js is asynchronous in nature, **the normal flow of execution will not work**.

You can achieve the above usecase, by making use of **promises** or **callbacks**.

These will help you to control the flow, i.e, execute the second function, only after first is executed completely.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the **findProduct()** function in body of then of **addProduct**.
Other ways are also first try this and reply.

```
   const addProduct = (req,res,next)=>{
        product.create({
        title:"Dhruv",
        imageUrl: "asdasdwadasd",
        description : 'How u doin'
    }).then(function(user){
        console.log("Product Created");
        findProduct();
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("cant create");
    });
    }
    addProduct();
    const findProduct = (req,res,next)=>{
        product.findAll().then(users => {
        console.log("Reached find all");
        console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
    });
    }
```

Comment: I know this will work, but this is a temporary solution. I want to know the right way to do this. I am making a website there will be lots of function calls, I can't keep on adding function calls inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are asynchronous functions. If the find query returns before the create is just because its processed quickly. If you want to be sure that the second one is executed after the first one had finished, you should call it inside the add callback. For example:

```
product.create({
    title: "Dhruv",
    imageUrl: "asdasdwadasd",
    description: 'How u doin'
}).then(function(user){
    console.log("Product Created");

    product.findAll().then(products => {
        console.log("Reached find all");
        console.log("All products:", JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("cant find");
    });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("cant create");
});
```